# How do I implement routing in a basic Wordpress SPA using Vanilla JS

Tags: ajax, wordpress, single-page-application

I am new to Web Developement and Wordpress. I am somewhat confused about how to do basic SPA routing using Wordpress

I have a site that uses Wordpress as a CMS, and uses AJAX to load content into a Div depending on which link is clicked by the user.

Links are Home, News etc.

The Home page is the default Index.php page.

When someone clicks on News some other data is loaded into the 'content' div.
I will then use pushstate to update the address bar to www.mysite.com/news.

But I am not sure how to get back to this point if www.mysite.com/news is directly entered into the address bar.

Currently wordpress just shows a sample news item when I put the above in directly, redirecting to www.mysite.com/2019/05/02/news-item/

I know this is a basic question, but I have done a lot of reading and there doesnt seem to any simple explanation for this on the internet I can find easily. Most of the tutorials use some framework and seem more complex than I want to implement.

Thanks,
mubarak

Answer (score 0):

It's very simple! Change your permalinks structure from the page:

```
yourdomain.com/wp-admin/options-permalink.php
```

to match your app's routing.